# IVideoWindow interface does not show video frames properly in UserControl

Tags: directshow, directshow.net

I am using DirectShow.NET library [ http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/ ] and I use below code in order to show video streams.

```
videowindow.put_Owner(handle);
videowindow.put_WindowStyle(WindowStyle.Child | WindowStyle.ClipChildren);
videowindow.put_WindowState(DirectShowLib.WindowState.Show);
```

Note: The handle is System.Windows.Forms.UserControl handle [ this->Handle]

**The problem is that:**

- In my user control the video frames are not shown properly: I see half
  of the video frame and the other half is out of screen.
- Also when I scale    my user control, the video stream frames are not
  scaled.

What may cause this ? How can i fix it?

**Update:**

Based on Roman Answer I added following code:

```
videoWindow.SetWindowPosition(this.ClientRectangle.Left,
                this.ClientRectangle.Top,
                this.ClientRectangle.Width,
                this.ClientRectangle.Height);
```

And Now I can able to see video frame in my user control rectangle properly....

Comment: Are you setting `IVideoWindow.SetWindowPosition`? You are also responsible to update it when layout of your window changes.

Comment: Roman, write your comment as an answer, I will accept it. Thanks Roman R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additionally to putting video renderer's window as a child control and providing window stypes, you should be setting `IVideoWindow.SetWindowPosition`. You are also responsible to update it when layout of your window changes.